# Empty flutter project to run in simulator takes 2 hours

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

When I checked in Xcode i can see that the bundle process is 8000+

[image: Here is the details]

added few libraries but nothing been used in project.

main.dart is pre created one and nothing changed in that too.

[image: Added Libraries]

Answer (score 0):

Exspecially the firebase libraries come with a lot of code that have a big impact on the building time.
You can try to use pre compiled libraries to speed up building time.

```
...
target 'Runner' do
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '6.34.0'
...
end
```

Have a look at the full article here: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/divide-by-5-the-build-time-of-your-firestore-app-with-a-single-line-35041ccf38f2

Comment: still same @josxha. not much improvement.